# Google charts in aspnet

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core

Hy, I want to generate a barchart in my pagemodel. The data is provided from my database.

```
public JsonResult GetData()
        {
            DataSet ds = GetViews();
            List<Alliances> listAllianceforCharts = new List<Alliances>();
            foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {
                listAllianceforCharts.Add(new Alliances
                {
                    Al = Convert.ToString(dr["Al"]),
                    Ci = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Ci"]),
                    So = Convert.ToInt32(dr["So"]),
                    Ta = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Ta"]),
                    Ai = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Ai"]),
                    Sh = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Sh"])
                });
            }
            return new JsonResult(listAllianceforCharts);
        }
```

```
google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            //Create our data table out of JSON data loaded from server.
            var jsonData = $.ajax({
                url: "/Index/GetData",
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST"
            });
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Al');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Ci');
            data.addColumn('number', 'So');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Ta');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Ai');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Shs');
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([jsonData[i].Al, jsonData[i].Ci, jsonData[i].So, jsonData[i].Ta, jsonData[i].Ai, jsonData[i].Sh]);
            };
            var options = {
                title: 'Mil Levels'
            };
            //Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
```

A chart without bars is created. I can see a data is returned to GetData. However, a chart is not being generated as expected. I wonder where I am doing wrong ? Is there a way for me to debug cshtml and see where did I go wrong >? How do I check if the page is getting data from pagemodel?

Comment: Try to use the developer console of your browser mostly `F12` will show it. Then you can check from there if there is some error. Also if you want to debug your javascript try to add `debugger;` to any line on your javascript make sure that your browser developer tool is also open for this.

Comment: Hy, ton. Thank you for your help. I can atleast now see the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you learn to use F12 debugging, you will find that `jsonData` variable does not accept the json data returned by `GetData`, so jsonData variable will not be able to add data in the loop.

What you need to understand is that when the execution of ajax is completed, that is, **after entering the GetData method to return json data, if there is no error, the program will immediately enter the success method of ajax, if you want to get the data returned by GetData, you must get it in the success method of ajax instead of your current jsonData variable**.

And it should be noted that if you are using the **core 3.1** version, the field names of the passed json data will become **camel case**, that is, the fields such as `Al, Ci` will become `ai, ci` in js.

To prevent this behavior, you need to add the following code to `ConfigureServices` in `startup.cs` file:

```
 services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(opts => opts.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null);
```

Here is the complete code:

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
    public JsonResult GetData()
    { 
         DataSet ds = GetViews();
        List<Alliances> listAllianceforCharts = new List<Alliances>();
        foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            listAllianceforCharts.Add(new Alliances
            {
                Al = Convert.ToString(dr["Al"]),
                Ci = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Ci"]),
                So = Convert.ToInt32(dr["So"]),
                Ta = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Ta"]),
                Ai = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Ai"]),
                Sh = Convert.ToInt32(dr["Sh"])
            });
        }
        return new JsonResult(listAllianceforCharts);
    }
}
```

Index View:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}
<h1>Index</h1>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
@section Scripts{

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script> 
        google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['corechart'] });
        google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
           $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/GetData", //url should be '/Controller/Action'
                dataType: "json",
                type: "POST",
                success: MyChart 
            }); 
        }
       

        //here jsonData received the json data from GetData action
        function MyChart(jsonData) { 
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Al');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Ci');
            data.addColumn('number', 'So');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Ta');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Ai');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Shs');
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonData.length; i++) {
                data.addRow([jsonData[i].Al, jsonData[i].Ci, jsonData[i].So, jsonData[i].Ta, jsonData[i].Ai, jsonData[i].Sh]);
            };
            var options = {
                title: 'Mil Levels'
            };
            //Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, options);
        }
    </script>
}
```

Here is the test result:

[image]